# "Connection failed" error in installing Mongodb in Windows

Tags: mongodb

I found a issue in installing MongoDb. When I run the command in CMD `Mongo.exe` I get this error. I have also make the directory in `C:/data/db`

> Hotfix Kb2731284 is installed no need to zero out data files
>        Exception: connection failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says Exception : Connect failed.

> Make sure that you are running mongodatabse server using mongod
>   command in a other terminal window.

1] open a terminal/cmd window and run

```
mongod
```

2] open another terminal/cmd window and run

```
mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Running this command 
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data

This error occurs When You it cannot find directory like "C:\data\db".which version of Windows are You using

Comment: I am using windows 7